# Rails Application#call is very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, middleware, rack

I'm seeing this `Application#call` take anywhere from 500 to 1500ms on every call which is soaking up memory on my Heroku dynos and causing timeouts.  Any idea how to figure out what's inside this `Application#call`?  Stuck on ideas. I replaced our app name with `AppName`.

[image: New Relic screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the deployments when this first started happening.  Turns out it was a beta gem version from Scoutapp.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if NewRelic is showing it this way, but `call` is part of Rack and where Rack passes a request off into your Rails app. Everything your Rails app does happens “under” that `call`.

If you want to dive into what parts of it are taking longer, hit “Track as key transaction” in NewRelic and give it a bit to accumulate traces. This will give you higher resolution reporting — i.e., you'll be able to expand the `call` section and see times for all of the methods that were called within your Rails app.

Typically you have synchronous HTTP requests (e.g. to third party APIs and services) causing the delay, but you might also have a CPU bound method or are getting hit by memory running into swap.